# Conditionally override templated class member variable

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Is it possible to override a class member variable based on the template parameter? If yes, how?

Roughly my problem: I have my array class (it is a dynamic array with some special functionality I need) as a base which looks like:

```
template<class T>
class Array
{
protected:
    uint size_;
    uint capacity_;
    T *data_;    // This is our array where we store the data
...
}
```

Now I have my own SOA class, which looks like:

```
template<uint N>
class SOA : public std::conditional_t<
                N == 1,
                Array<double>,
                Array<Array<double>>>
{
protected:
    Array<double> data_[N]; /* I need it ONLY IF N > 1, else we get the data_ member from Array<T> */
...
}
```

The N denotes how much arrays are we storing in the class.
So the condition for the base class is simply check if we have 1 component, and fall back to an Array, or if we have more, it is an Array of arrays -> Array<Array>

But what I would like to do, is override the data_ member from the Array class IF N > 1. Since it is a fixed size, I could simply use Array data_[N], so it can be a stack allocated array instead of a heap allocated one.
So basically what I need is to define the data_ member based on the template parameter.

My other idea is to inherit form `Array<T>` IF N==1, if not then don't inherit but in this case I still have to conditionally define the data_ member and also i wasn't able to do it.

I know for N=1 I could use `Array<T>` simply instead of this class but I want them to be the same class since it will be a HUGE simplification for my code if I don't have to deal with different classes for N=1, and all I have to deal with is a `SOA<N>` class and that's all.

And if it isn't possible I will simply create a stack allocated array for every `SOA<N>` and for N=1 I'll simply store one array in it. But it would be nice if it could act like a simple `Array<T>` if N=1

Thanks in advance!

Edit: More detail why I want it to be an array. If I have a -> 1 component, and b -> 3 component, and I would like to multiply a with the 1st component of B, then I1ll have to multiply a `SOA<T>` with an `Array<T>`. If I store NCMPT=1 in a 1 sized array, then I'll always have to extract it's 1st and only component so the classes are matching. Or I have to define a lot of operators for them...

**SOLUTION:**

In my case the N is extracted from a struct of type STYPE.

So this is my final working solution. Simple specialisation wasn't enough btw this solution was pretty obvious...

So the class holds Arrays in a C style array called data_.

BUT! if the given STYPE T has exactly one component, then and only then inherit from Array. (SDTYPE tells the data type for an STYPE)

```
template<STYPE T>
class SOA
{
public:
    typedef typename SDTYPE<T>::type value_type;
private:
    Array<value_type> data_[T.NCMPT];
}

template<STYPE T>
requires(T.NCMPT == 1)
class SOA<T>
    : public Array<typename SDTYPE<T>::type>
{
}
```

Comment: You should provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to better explain your problem, otherwise, it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: The problem is that my Array class is pretty big and I can't shrink it down to be a fair sized but working code. But my main problem is what I wrote. Simply define a class member based on the template parameter. And I can't do it so I can't give a minimal working example... So it is not a why is it not working, but a how could it be done problem...

Comment: @Ruks I removed the redundant stuff from the problems perspective. But I can't give a better example since I have no idea if it is even possible to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is a [*partial template specialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization):

```cpp
// This specialization of the class will be used when N > 1
template<uint N>
class SOA : public std::conditional_t<N == 1, Array<double>, Array<Array<double>>> {
protected:
    Array<double> data_[N];

    // ...
};

// This specialization will be used when N = 1
template <>
class SOA<1> {
    // ...
};
```

Do keep in mind that this feature is limited to only C++14 and above.

Comment: OMG that was too obvious. Yes, exactly, thank you. But more specially to my exact problem I have to use requires(N=1) after the template since I don't pass the N but a struct which stores the N.

Comment: @simre It should still work even if you pass the value for N from a struct, it just needs to be a constant value.

Comment: But in that case I'll have to extract the value from N with requires or enable_if since i can't specialise only based on N but I have to decide if the template is appropriate based on a value inside N. BTW I'll test it and I'm using C++20 so this is all fine for me. I just didn't saw the tree because of the forest...

Comment: So I made some tests. I edited my question, But I had to use requires for the specialisation and now it is working as I expected.